# I need to deploy my software on other machines along with the database

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I have created a movie ticket booking system, and I need to deploy it on some other machine. I am facing a problem for the database. When I deployed my software on the other machine, it got installed but due to absence of SQL server it didn't work. So, I installed SQL server there. But still it showed me problem with server name parameters I gave in `SqlConnection`. I made changes over there. Now again I'm facing problems with data bindings.

I'm having to change everything again and again. Is there any simple and efficient solution for this?

Help me achieve the following:

- Providing database along with the project when I deploy it.
- If I attach my database on other machine, I want to use my existing data binding.
- I don't want to change database server name again and again for every connection I made.

Comment: If you're creating a movie booking system, shouldn't you just have one instance of SQL Server somewhere (e.g. on a server) and have all your client applications point to it over the network? There's no need to have SQL Server on every machine.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL services are running on newly installed machine?

Comment: Where's it getting the server/instance name from now? A config file is the usual way. It shouldn't matter to your code where the database is, except knowing where it is. That said there are a whole raft of potential other issues deployment wise with what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

- Providing database along with the project when i deploy it.

It's difficult to a 'one-click' install for both the database and GUI. But you can use versioning or timestamping your deployment items to keep those like items together. Source control those items to be able to rollback and bring up the versions you need on demand. Have some way to tie the version numbers or timestamps together with the GUI components to associate a deployment as one unit.

For example, you can version your change db scripts (FooTable v100, v101, v102) or timestamp them then check them into source control. Store the various associations in some type of configuration db. At my work, we use a SharePoint list to itemize deployments and use the SharePoint list item references to reference all the different items for a particular change together. Since everything is sourced controlled, I can easily figure out and retrieve the deployments items for a particular change if need be.

- If i attach my database on other machine, I want to use my existing
  data binding.
- I don't want to change database server name again and again for every
  connection i made.

You can use connection strings that use trusted connections such as

Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;

so you don't need to embed different username and pws for each environment. You can store the server and database names in machine.config or web.config on each respective environment server(s).

So on dev, the ConnectionString could be

Data Source=myDevServer;Initial Catalog=myDevDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;

on test:

Data Source=myTestServer;Initial Catalog=myTestDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;

If you store them in the configuration file on the server, you don't need to change it within the package.

In the case you do need to store that config with the package, you should use techniques to dynamically change the settings based on the environment you are deploying to. For example, you could use environment variables to determine which environment you are on so  that you know which code to run to change the configs dynamically. Or instead of code, you could use XSLT to change the XML config. There are also custom actions you can set in MSI to run on install/uninstall. You could add code there to change the config as needed on deployment.

Likewise, the database scripts themselves can change based on the environment you are deploying on. You can use SQLCMD variables to dynamically change SQL code (in particular the database and server names in 3 and 4 part naming references, i.e. devlinkserver.devdb.dbo.foo can change to testlnkserver.testdb.dbo.foo if you replace devlinkserver and devdb with SQLCML variables). Use SQLCMDs scripting to change the variable values as needed based on the environment you are deploying to:

IF @@SERVER = 'somedevdbserver'

SET :linkserver = 'DevDBServer'

IF @@SERVER = 'sometestserver'

SET :linkserver = 'testDBServer'

etc...

In summary, keep as much configuration the same as you can across all environments. Use various techniques described above to dynamically change the config as needed for the parts that need to be different on each environment.